# How to add image in POST request Java?

Tags: java

There is the following code:

```
private static String doPostRequest(List<NameValuePair> params, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

    return getContentFromInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
} 

private static String getContentFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So, how can I add some image (for example, File f) to my POST request? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This was part of Servlet 3's "multi part file upload".

You would build up a blob of the image then post it to a Servlet 3 endpoint.

Take a look at the examples [here](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)

If you plan on using Spring, that has some really nice easy annotations to define your controllers which will work with file upload you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/keesun/1604411)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MultipartRequestEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/MultipartRequestEntity.html) .

```
        File f = new File(filePath);
        PostMethod postMessage = new PostMethod(urlString);
        Part[] parts = {
                new StringPart("param", "value"),
                new FilePart(f.getName(), f)
        };
        postMessage.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, postMessage.getParams()));
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        int status = client.executeMethod(postMessage);
```